Why can't I sync gradle and got these 2 errors?

This is the first time I'm using Android Studio and I have problems with Gradle sync like "could not move temporary workspace" and "C:\Users\Rafa.gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\742535973f29a02b9fcea84e9576fac3-4419df33-2a83-434b-9a05-1c1cef25fa05 -> C:\Users\Rafa.gradle\caches\8.8\transforms\742535973f29a02b9fcea84e9576fac3"

I've already tried many ways, such as invalidate caches & restart, download gradle from the website, configure the file properties, even re-install it but still doesn't work.

Please do not post screenshots of errors. Instead simply post the error text from Gradle build log and format it as code..

Try to fix it with next steps:

try to delete manually gradle from its current directory ->
\Users\Rafa.gradle\caches
and After that reopen Android Studio to re-download the necessary files.
Make sure you have enough free space on your disk in which you installed Android Studio.
Do you have latest gradle version? otherwise install the new one and try.
Try to run your Android studio as administrator (if the case) because of sometimes file permissions cause issues when Gradle tries to move files.

